# Connect to virtual host from local network

Tags: routing, bind

Configured bind9, apache and all related services.

Problem is;
I am able to connect to my sites from outside, www.mysite.com (example) is ok. In such case my - client IP is different than servers IP.

But when I try to connect the same way but through common modem to which my server is connected too, no connection can be established. I mean, me with my laptop with local IP 192.168.1.2 can not connect to server with local IP 192.168.1.10 by using www.mysite.com.
Only with 192.168.1.10/mysite.com.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to employ a technique called [hairpinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) to access local servers using their external IP address.

A simpler option might be to add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file (on that laptop) that maps www.mysite.com to that local IP address 192.168.1.10, or to let your internal DNS server do that mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

hosts solution is not professional. Now I am able to access my virtual hosted domain via 192.168.1.10/example.com.

Researched about hairpinning. But couldn't managed to properly modify my router/modem. No records in server's logs. So I think an answer hides in router/modem. Will update again when I will find right solution.

Comment: Good luck. What type of modem/router is it? Maybe someone can help you to configure hairpinning on it.

Comment: Inca. I have contacted them and they confirmed that loopback feature is not supported on their modems. If I am not wrong, then Zyxel models do that.